# How to add function name into `logging.basicConfig`'s argument `format` in Kur?

Tags: python, logging

**The Problem**

When `kur -v data mnist.yml`, the `logger.info` will generate a logging header like `[INFO 2017-04-10 10:33:41,108 kur.kurfile:97]`.

However, it only provides folder name `kur` and filename `kurfile`, how can I add a function name? Is there an easy way to achieve it by changing the code below?

The format of this header is defined below inside `kur.__main__.main()`:

```
config = logging.basicConfig if args.no_color else logcolor.basicConfig
config(
    level=loglevel.get(args.verbose, logging.DEBUG),
    format='{color}[%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(name)s:%(lineno)s]{reset} '
    '%(message)s'.format(
        color='' if args.no_color else '$COLOR',
        reset='' if args.no_color else '$RESET'
    )
)
```

---

solution based on the answer suggested by @Harvey below:

```
config = logging.basicConfig if args.no_color else logcolor.basicConfig
    config(
        level=loglevel.get(args.verbose, logging.DEBUG),
        format='{color}[%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(name)s %(funcName)s:%(lineno)s]{reset} '
        '%(message)s'.format(
            color='' if args.no_color else '$COLOR',
            reset='' if args.no_color else '$RESET'
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `%(funcName)` from the documentation for [logging.LogRecord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord)

Comment: Thanks, I inserted `%(funcName)s` in the code above, and it works.

Comment: Oops. Fixed. Thanks.